# JOptionPane: parentComponent does not have a valid parent - Trying to display an error message

Tags: java

I am trying to get user input with a JOptionPane dialog box. I want to display an error message if the input is empty, but can't get the box for the error message working.

```
if (e.getSource() == atmDone) {
        String groupName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the group name");

        if (groupName.isEmpty()==false){
            PrintStream output;
            try {
                output = new PrintStream(new File(groupName + ".txt"));
                output.println(textArea.getText());
                output.close();

                System.out.println("here");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (groupName.isEmpty()){
            error = new JFrame();
            JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(error, "Group couldn't be saved: name empty", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
```

The error I'm receiving says that parentComponent does not have a valid parent.
What should I use as the parent in order to display the error message?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not using the "internal frame" version of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, so why are you trying to do so with the error message?

Comment: String groupName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(`null`, "Enter the group name");

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the parent argument in JOptionPane methods.  A JOptionPane, or any dialog for that matter, will be *associated* with its parent, so that anytime the user brings that parent window into focus, the dialog will also be displayed.  Also, prompt dialogs such as those displayed by JOptionPane are usually *modal* to that parent, meaning they prevent the user from interacting with the parent window until the dialog is closed.

For those reasons, it is a good idea to always specify a valid parent.  Your first JOptionPane statement should be:

```
String groupName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(atmDone.getTopLevelAncestor(), "Enter the group name");
```

Your second JOptionPane call should use the same parent.  The error message you’re seeing is due to your having chosen the wrong method.  All JOptionPane methods with `Internal` in their name require the presence of a JDesktopPane as a parent or ancestor of the supplied parent, since those methods display their dialog as a JInternalFrame.

You can resolve the problem by using a method whose name does not contain the word `Internal`:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(atmDone.getTopLevelAncestor(),
    "Group couldn't be saved: name empty", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```